# Can abstract class be override in derived class without implementing in base class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have an abstract class `A` with one abstract method.

This class is inherited by another class, `B`, that should not implement the abstract method.

Now another class, `C`, needs to inherit from class `B` and implement the method defined in  class `A`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

You would need to mark class `B` as an abstract class as well if it's not going to implement all of the abstract members of its base class. Then, just override as normal in class `C`.

Example:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void DoStuff();
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    // Empty
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: But ClassA property or method cannot override directly in ClassC.

Comment: But ClassA property or Method cannot override in ClassC without implementing that method in classB.Any example for this?

Comment: I added an example.  FishBaskedGordo, feel free to remove if you don't like it.

Comment: So, we cannot implement non abstract class members of ClassA in ClassC.

Comment: @user490112: I think you're over complicating this. If `A` declares a either a `virtual` or `abstract` method, then any class lower in the hierarchy (`B`, `C`, or anything else that derives from `A`) can override it.

Comment: @user490112 You can override abstract and virtual methods of class `A` in class `C` just like normal. If you want to override a non-abstract/non-virtual method, you can do that using the `new` keyword. The problem is class B. You either have to mark it as abstract or implement the abstract members of `A`. If you didn't, class `B` would violate the interface contract; instances of class `B` wouldn't exhibit an "is-a" relationship with class `A`.